# How to write efficient XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I recently found these tips in a [post](https://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200006/msg00088.html) from year 2000:

> Eight tips for how to write efficient XSLT:
>
> 1. Avoid repeated use of "//item".
> 2. Don't evaluate the same node-set more than once; save it in a variable.
> 3. Avoid <xsl:number> if you can. For example, by using position().
> 4. Use <xsl:key>, for example to solve grouping problems.
> 5. Avoid complex patterns in template rules. Instead, use <xsl:choose> within the rule.
> 6. Be careful when using the preceding[-sibling] or following[-sibling] axes. This often indicates an algorithm with n-squared performance.
> 7. Don't sort the same node-set more than once. If necessary, save it as a result tree fragment and access it using the node-set() extension function.
> 8. To output the text value of a simple #PCDATA element, use <xsl:value-of> in preference to <xsl:apply-templates>.
>
> Mike Kay

Obviously, this advice relates to XSLT 1.0. My question is how much are these tips still relevant today with XSLT 3.0? I realize that performance can vary between different processors, so I am tagging this question as Saxon, since that is the processor I currently use.

I am particularly interested in tips #5 and #8 because these are the ones I often see being ignored today. The other ones seem to me as self evident at all times.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect I might have written that myself...

These days I think I would confine myself to one meta-tip - don't do anything to improve performance unless you first have a reliable measurement framework to assess the impact. If you can measure performance reliably, then improving it is usually very easy, if you can't then it's impossible.

Optimizers are certainly smarter now than they were in 2000, but they are also a lot less predictable. For example, they'll do a very good job with some flavours of xsl:number, but struggle with others. That means (a) you need to make your own measurements, and (b) it's a good idea to write code that doesn't rely too heavily on the optimizer if you can. For example, define explicit keys rather than relying on the optimizer to work out where introducing an index would be useful. Another example, move code out of a loop into a variable rather than relying on the optimizer to do it for you.

The other advice I would give is to read before you code. Don't copy and paste code from other people if you don't understand what it does. Don't use "//" rather than "/" on the basis that "I don't really understand the difference but that's what worked last time". The worst inefficiencies come from code written by people who just didn't understand what they were writing.

As regards #5, there are two things that can make template rules inefficient: one is having lots of complex template rules that involve repeated effort to see which of them applies, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="a[.//x[1]='foo']"/>
<xsl:template match="a[.//x[1]='bar']"/>
<xsl:template match="a[.//x[1]='baz']"/>
.. plus 20 more similar ..
```

Here the problem is that each node is being tested against many different rules. (Saxon-EE now goes to some lengths to try and optimise that, but it doesn't always succeed)

and the second is single template rules that do expensive navigation:

```
<xsl:template match="a[count(preceding::a) = 1]"/>
```

Here the problem is typically that testing many nodes individually against this predicate is less efficient than a bulk query to find all of those nodes in a single pass; it will often be better to select the nodes that meet the criteria first, and then test each node to see if it is a member of this set.

(Again, in this particular example Saxon will probably manage to optimize it: with `count(XXX) = 1` it should stop evaluating XXX once it knows there is more than one. Without that optimization, you could be counting 100,000 nodes and then comparing 100,000 with 1 and finding it's not a match.)

As regards #8, I've no idea why that's in the list, I very much doubt this is something likely to affect the bottom line significantly.

Comment: Could you nevertheless say something specific about tips #5 and #8?. I am not trying to solve performance issues; I am merely looking for some general rules to adapt as good practice. I understood the underlying idea here as "if you know what to do, then do it directly and save the processor the trouble of searching for the most suitable template". Wouldn't this still be a good rule to follow?

Comment: Thank you. The problem I see with your answer is that it could be interpreted to mean that there is no good practice to follow and everything is equally good unless you have a test to prove otherwise. I don't think it's practical to test every possible option. Some general rules are necessary. You say don't rely too heavily on the optimizer. But if those tips are no longer relevant, then how exactly do you that?

Comment: The good practice to follow is (a) to write clean code that's elegant, straightforward, and readable, and (b) to set performance targets based on business requirements, measure your code against those requirements, and only make any changes for performance effect if the changes are needed to enable you to meet those requirements.

Comment: I would also add, it's not that there is no good practice to follow, it's that any attempt to reduce it to a few rules of thumb is going to be deeply flawed. To get good performance, there's no escaping that (a) you need a deep understanding of the technology you are using, and (b) you need to take a professional and methodical approach to performance engineering.

Answer (score 1):

I think that many XSLT processor have learned to optimize `//item`, nevertheless of course many beginners through in too much of `//` into their expressions, sometimes without wanting/needing at all, both by starting what should be a relative path with it or by throwing it in the middle of path expressions. But I would say that a justified use where you need you want to search a nested subtree for `item` elements is fine.

I would think that with XSLT 2 and 3 of course you would use `xsl:for-each-group` for grouping and usually not a key. Performance that way should be as well as with a key only that some `xsl:for-each-group` code might be easier to maintain and understand than equivalent Muenchian grouping code.

While `xsl:number` of course for complex uses can perform bad, I would nevertheless think that it has its uses in XSLT 2 and/or 3 where you can't get all done with `position()`. Of course XSLT 3 has accumulators that might help solve many cases that `xsl:number` previously did.

General hints for XSLT 2/3 in terms of good coding and hopefully good performance are to use the `as` attribute to declare the types of variables, parameters and function results.

Also most parameter/variable bindinds are better done with `xsl:variable name="foo" select="some-xpath-expression"` or `xsl:param name="foo" select="some-xpath-expression"` than the nested `<xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="some-xpath-expression"/></xsl:variable>` beginners tend to use.

I am not a heavy user of schema-aware XSLT 2 and/or 3 but I think Michael Kay in the past has mentioned that it gives you additional improved error messages and safety if you validate both your input and output.

In XSLT 2/3, to return the result of an `xsl:function`, I would say use `xsl:sequence` usually and probably never `xsl:value-of` (as the letter creates a text node and not e.g. a boolean, a string or a sequence of some values or whatever value the `select` expression of `xsl:sequence` returns).

`xsl:iterate` is also a new feature in XSLT 3 meant to allow you to avoid performance problems in the form of stack overflow recursion problems.

#5 I have never heard in the context of performance problems but rather with the question as how to structure your code and in my view 80 or 90 % are rather in favour of various templates than using a single one that inside uses `xsl:choose/xsl:when`.

#8 also surprises me, I certainly of rely on the identity transformation (now declared in XSLT 3 with `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"`) to simply have text node values copied through without needing to explicitly having them output with `xsl:value-of`.

Anyway, I would think that writing declarative code like XSLT 3 is not done with the priority of having it perform well, if some of my XSLT performs really bad I would look into measuring what exactly causes it and how to remedy it but would not be permanently preoccupied by using or avoiding constructs for performance reasons.